# Custom ios app nav bar buttons

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar

I'm having problems to create an custom nav bar like the [Uber app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/uber/id368677368?mt=8).

[image: screenshot]

I'm setting my button background image to:

```
UIImage *button44 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navButtonAdd"]
                     resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:button44 forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But If I remove the text from the button on the xcode interface it disappear the image as well and also there is a padding on the right that starts repeating my image again.

[image: screenshot]

Does anyone know how I could fix it?

This is the image I'm trying to use as a button

[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please update your post with an image showing the buttons you are referring to. That would be much better than making people go to the app store and trying to figure which screen shot and which buttons you mean.

Comment: haven't tested the app, but does its "Navigation Bar" also acts like a casual UINavigationBar? I think its not just a custumized UINavigationBar, but a normal UIView or similar, because the usual items are not able to get "free form" like in the app. btw, facing the same issue next time :)

Comment: @geo yes, it acts like a casual nav bar when using the app. Just the buttons are different.

rmaddy sorry about that, thanks Jano for editing my post.

Comment: “How do they do that” type of questions are off topic. Try to replicate the behavior and post any specific doubt you encounter. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142857/ For example, what's the problem with `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uberbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];` ?

Comment: @Jano ok, sorry about that. I've update my question with what I've tried so far, let me know if it's ok now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button"]]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uberbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

If I'm not mistaken you need a custom view on the UIBarButtonItem. So you could get the appearance proxy, set the image for the controller, or instead customize the image directly. That padding is a matter of photoshopping the graphic and set its dimensions correctly.

Comment: thanks for your help, I'm kinda new to IOS so I will try the basic style nav for now with customized buttons, I tried your solution and didn't worked, but I'm sure I did it wrong in some way, I have my custom nav bar pattern already and the top code doesn't seems to replace the default button style

Comment: Post a github example with same size graphic assets, and ask again. Likely someone will be willing to fork it and fix it.